# Java HTTP request read response body

Tags: java, http, httprequest

How can I read the body of a HTTP request?. I was searching for a simple way and I think this is the easiest.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.y.com/url");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
try {
  /* Now read the retrieved document from the stream. */
  ...
} finally {
  is.close();
}
```

But how can i read this or print errors in the console? Is there an easier way to make the request and read the response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i read this or print in the console please

Use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and try with resources:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.y.com/url");
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
    br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 9+,you can use `HttpClient`,`HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse`.

```java
HttpClient client=HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request=HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(new URI(your url)).GET().build();
HttpResponse<String> response=client.send(request,BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.body());
```